# Translating "my work started here" to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How do you translate to Latin "my work started here"?
It is for a plaque on a commemorative bench.

Answer (score 4):

I would write "opus meum hic incepit"

- opus = work, action of working
- meum = my
- hic = here
- incepit = started

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is *incipere* also used so that the work is the subject? I only recall seeing the worker as the subject, but I certainly haven't seen everything.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It's less common (rare in Classical prose), but it is a thing. See II. under the Lewis and Short definition.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest:

> *Hic opus inii.*
> "Here I started work."

It is common in classical Latin to use *inire* for starting a job of some kind (e.g. *imperium, magistratum inire*).
*Opus* is used for many kinds of work, including works of art.
I don't think an explicit "my" is needed here, as the person is clear from the verb.

I like a succinct phrasing like this, and it seems not to suffer from any serious ambiguity either.

Answer (score 2):

Succinctness is one way to go about it, but I instead would opt for formality.

**IN HOC LOCO OPVS COEPI**

"In this place/on this site I began my work."

The bonus of using *coepi* is that it recalls *annuit coeptis* of the Great Seal of the US, which, even if you're not in the US, will still make it broadly recognizable.